# HAproxy subdomain redirect

Tags: linux, haproxy

I own one domain like xyz.com and I'm trying to redirect subdomain other ip with haproxy.

I use tomcat on the servers and I use haproxy to redirect incoming requests on port 80 to port 8080.

```
Like;

www.xyz.com -> 10.0.0.1

www.xyz.com/abc -> 10.0.0.2
  or  abc.xyz.com -> 10.0.0.2
```

In order to do this redirection, how do I set haproxy?

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted 3 times and without any comment. This is not a very good stackexchange etiquette! Sorry for this bad welcome.

Answer (score 13):

In haproxy you do redirection combining `acl` rules and `redirect` ones; you choose the right server using the `backend` rule.

The official [haproxy documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt) is not very easy to read, but it's very complete.

Something like this (just a sketch to give you an idea):

```
frontend http-in
    mode              http
    bind              FRONTENDIP:80 # eg. 100.100.100.100:80

    default_backend   tomcat_server_2

    acl tomcat_1      hdr_end(host) -i www.xyz.com
    acl tomcat_2      hdr_end(host) -i abc.xyz.com
    acl tomcat_path   path_beg /abc/

    use_backend       tomcat_server_1 if tomcat_1 !tomcat_path

backend tomcat_server_1
    server tomcat1 10.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 1000

backend tomcat_server_2
    server tomcat2 10.0.0.2:8080 maxconn 1000
```

If you want to *redirect* `www.xyz.com/abc/` to `abc.xyz.com` :

```
    redirect prefix   http://abc.xyz.com if tomcat_path
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I think the second `backend tomcat_server_1` should be `backend tomcat_server_2`

Comment: doesn't work.  It is putting it on the end instead of the prefix.

Answer (score -3):

Haproxy is neither meant to redirect names nor to redirect URIs.

Names are directed by name servers (DNS).

URIs are redirected by (modules of) a webserver (HTTP).

Haproxy is to balance traffic (TCP/IP) between two (or more) identical servers.

Comment: haproxy can very well redirect both prefixes (subdomain/domain/etc.) and urls. Search for `redirect location` and `redirect prefix` in http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt

Comment: You 're wrong, Haproxy is both a load balancer and a reverse proxy server.